# python nested lists and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, nested

I have an output from a code where coordinates of several rectangles (four corners x,y) are provided in a list of arrays containing nested lists, which looks as follows:

```
[array([[[x1, y1],
        [x2, y2],
        [x3, y3],
        [x4, y4]]], dtype=float32), 
...
array([[[x1, y1],
        [x2, y2],
        [x3, y3],
        [x4, y4]]], dtype=float32)]
```

I have another list of corresponding rectangle IDs. which looks like that :

```
[[310]
 [401]
...
 [203]
 [181]]
```

They are in the same order as the coordinates.
I want to mashup both lists to get the following data structure:

```
[[rect_ID, [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)],
[rect_ID, [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)],
...
[rect_ID, [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)]]
```

I need then to sort the list by the rect_ID

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: To be picky - your initial list contains 2 arrays, each of which is 2d.  They don't contain nested lists (though their `.tolist()` output would be nested lists).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using list comprehensions.

**Explanation:** You loop over the combination of two lists (`coords` and `ids`) since they map one to one. `i[0]` gives you the index and `j.flatten()` converts each array of your `coords` into a single 1d array. The task then is to create pairs of coordinates as tuples. To do so, first you get every even indexed elements starting from 0 in steps of 2 using `[0::2]` and every odd indexed element starting from 1 in steps of 2 using `[1::2]`. Using zip, you combine them in pairs and then finally use `list` to convert them into a list `[]`.

Finally you sort the `final` list using the id (first element) as the key.

```
# Sample data (Just taken for example purpose)
coords = [np.array([[[1, 2],
        [2,1],
        [3,2],
        [4,4]]]), 

np.array([[[3,2],
        [1,2],
        [1,4],
        [5,6]]]),

np.array([[[12,2],
        [1,21],
        [1,14],
        [15,6]]])]

ids = [[310],
 [181],[123]]
```

---

**Code**

```
final = [[i[0], list(zip(j.flatten()[0::2], j.flatten()[1::2]))] for i, j in zip(ids, coords)]

result = sorted(final, key=lambda x: x[0])
print (result)
```

**Output**

```
[[123, [(12, 2), (1, 21), (1, 14), (15, 6)]],
[181, [(3, 2), (1, 2), (1, 4), (5, 6)]],
[310, [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 4)]]]
```

Comment: That works! Much appreciated for the excellent and prompt answer!